# Python 3: Making a variable with a part of a list and a standard part and then assing that variable to a newly created list

Tags: string, list, python-3.7

I need to convert some strings into a list, and one that consists of other lists. 
First part of the code:

```
ww_onconverted = input("enter raw data:")
ww_spaces_to_tabs = ww_onconverted.replace(" ", "\t")
ww_spaces_to_tabs = ww_spaces_to_tabs.replace("-", " ")
ww_splitted = ww_spaces_to_tabs.split("\t")
print(ww_splitted)
```

So when I enter: 
abrir   abriendo    abierto abro,es,e,imos,en   abrí,iste,ió,imos,ieron abría,s,-,mos,n abriré,ás,á,emos,án abre,abra

He makes a list like this:
['abrir', 'abriendo', 'abierto', 'abro,es,e,imos,en', 'abrí,iste,ió,imos,ieron', 'abría,s, ,mos,n', 'abriré,ás,á,emos,án', 'abre,abra']

This is the right direction but I then want to make a list:

```
ww_splitted[0]_gerundio = [ww_splitted[1]]
```

So when I use the info that I just entered, the code needs to make this:
`abrir_gerundio = abriendo`

This multiple times and then I want to make a list called 
`ww_splitted[0] = [ww_splitted[0]_gerundio]`

I tried to use the functions globals(), locals() and exec(), but the didn't work out for me because I don't really understand them, I searched for them on the internet but did not get much further than there basic examples, probably because of my bad English.
Could anyone help me?

-Blenrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output does not look like a list, but rather a dictionary, which is also better suited for what you are doing.

```
dict = {ww_splitted[0]+"_gerundio" : ww_splitted[1]}
```